Differential pair 3-stage oscillator does not oscillate even satisfy the conditions of oscillation
I am building a differential pair 3-stage oscillator.
For a single stage, small-signal AC gain is very high at low-frequency.
I also checked the negative feedback for every stage like minus out plus in, vice versa.
The oscillator still does not work.



What am I doing wrong? Which numbers should I tune further?
My current tail gate is 100uA.
I also include my transient response. The initial condition is vx_2 = 1.2 V and vy_2 = 5mV

Are you sure about the polarities? The stages seem like in positive feedback to me. The circuit will just latchup to either rail.
